# Передать данные из одного компонента в другой в Битриксе

Tags: шаблоны, компоненты, битрикс

Доброго времени суток.

Я только начал изучение 1С-Битрикс! Я хотел бы узнать, как можно данные из одного компонента использовать в другом. Например, у меня есть компонент `news.list`, который в себе содержит даты публикации. Мне нужно эти даты передать в компонент `catalog.filter`. Вернее даже не в компонент, а сразу в шаблон можно. Как в битриксе это можно сделать по уму? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас компонент news.list и catalog.filter находятся на одной странице шаблона комплексного компонента, то вы можете поступить следующим образом:

1. Добавить нужную вам информацию в массив $arResult при помощи файла result_modifier.php в шаблоне компонента news.list: `$arResult["INFO"] = ...`
2. Добавить эту информацию к кешу компонента в том же файле result_modifier.php: 
   `if (is_object($this->__component))
   {
       $this->__component->SetResultCacheKeys(array('INFO'));
       if (!isset($arResult['INFO']))
           $arResult['INFO'] = $this->__component->arResult['INFO'];
   }`
3. В файле component_epilog.php шаблона компонента news.list записать эту информацию в массив $arResult шаблона родительского комплексного компонета: `if(is_object($this->__parent))
       if($this->__parent->arResult)
           $this->__parent->arResult["INFO"] = $arResult["INFO"];`
4. Добавить в шаблоне комплексного компонента к параметрам компонента catalog.filter сохраненную информацию: `"INFO"=>$arResult["INFO"],`
5. В шаблоне компонента catalog.filter взять информацию из массива $arParams: `$arParams["~INFO"]`

У данного метода правда есть ограничение: в шаблоне комплексного компонента код вызова компонента news.list должен находится перед вызовом catalog.filter.